# SciLab - Stack size exceeded

Tags: variables, memory, stack, scilab, exceed

So, I have this project for school in which I have to write code in SciLab to solve a puzzle (Tents). The code is getting longer and longer as it gets better and better, but I suddenly got an error stating "stack size exceeded".

```
Error log:
!--error 17 
stack size exceeded!
Use stacksize function to increase it.
Memory used for variables: 28875
Intermediate memory needed: 59987764
Total memory available: 10000000
```

I tried using this line

```
stacksize('max')
```

And this one

```
stacksize(1e8)
```

Neither of which works, all that happens is SciLab shutting itself down without any warning at all.

How did I exceed my stacksize? Is there a way to prevent this? How can I continue further?

Comment: Which platform do you use (win/linux 32/64)? What size of RAM do you have? The command `stacksize('max')` shuts SciLab instantly, or the calculation done after the command?

Comment: I use win 64 with 8GB of RAM. Scilab shuts down instantly when I run the program.
Sorry for the late respond btw, hope you'll still notice this :)

Comment: Does `stacksize('max')` command in clean file coredumps Scilab?

Comment: First, I like the "The code is getting longer and longer as it gets better and better" quote. That aside, could you provide your code? Is there any recursion in there, or a big amount of for-loops? Probably you'll have to refactor your code, to calculate everything step-by-step and not all in one go. But this will be easier to see if you give the code or a description of the problem/your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out myself how to solve this problem. Here's what I did wrong for people with the same problem:

Within a function I used the line

```
[m,n] = [x,y]
```

to save the coordinates of an object from a matrix. This was called within a loop using x and y to browse through the matrix.

Apparently this caused the stacksize exceeded error and here's how I wrote it afterwards:

```
m = x
n = y
```

I have no idea why this line caused this error, but this is how I've solved it.